# Show different slider for different selections in dat.gui

Tags: three.js, dat.gui

I have a gui where the use can select different shapes to render with a dropdown. This works well. Now I wanna display a folder with some slider. The count, name and min/max values of the sliders differ in which shape is selected. How can I accomplish this with dat.gui.

Comment: Folder - do you mean a dom element? On select change you want to add dom elements and update values. You can use onChange event [example](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#7--Events)

Comment: I mean the DOM element added with `gui.addFolder`.

Comment: Can't you update values on select change? [example how to update](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#10--Updating-the-Display-Manually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found  a solution by adding this to the dat.GUI prototype:

```
dat.GUI.prototype.removeFolder = function(name) {
  var folder = this.__folders[name];
  if (!folder) {
    return;
  }
  folder.close();
  this.__ul.removeChild(folder.domElement.parentNode);
  delete this.__folders[name];
  this.onResize();
}
```